# How many times did Cage relive that day in "Edge of Tomorrow"?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

How many times did Cage relive that day in *Edge of Tomorrow*? We see him wake up many times in the movie, but there seem to be many, many more instances that we don't see. For instance, at the farmhouse, he has already lived that several times, though we only see two of them.

Is there any way to know how many times he relives that day?

Comment: Also the training montage, there's no way he became that proficient at killing Mimics with just what was onscreen

Comment: Wasn't part of the mystery how many times the day was repeated? Even if you knew, what does it matter? 1-No more mystery, 2-Time Travel, 3-Any particular repeated day feels like any other repeated day, and thus no particular repeat matters, only the whole experience.

Comment: Groundhog day was over 30 years. This one had too be similar for his training , not to mention how many times he ran and got drunk.

Comment: I'd say we factor in the estimated amount of time required to be that proficient at combat against the mimics, plus an estimate of the length of time a person of his caliber can go through the despair phase.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not directly stated in the movie and there are plenty of days that happened off-screen, making counting by viewers impossible.

However this same question was [asked over on the Movies & TV Stack Exchange site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/21189) and it was stated that there were 160 days in the book that the movie is based on.

> It doesn't appear to be discussed in the movie.
>
> In the book the film is based on, [All You Need is Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Kill), he has
>   **160** iterations.
>
> There's an [interesting thread](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631867/board/thread/230689934?p=3) over at IMDB you might want to
>   peruse, where people have argued everything from 100 days to over 1000
>   days, to over 100 years! There isn't any common consensus on that
>   thread (or indeed across the Internet, yet) on how long the loop
>   lasted for *in the film*.

Comment: From the amount of training he's gotten, especially given each failure resulted in reset, 160 sounds way too low :)

Answer (score 1):

Rita Vitowski actually states she watched Hendrix die 300 times, thus she went through 300 days, it's entirely possible to think he may have done equal or greater.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is an interesting piece of trivia, but it doesn't actually answer the question.  Even that it approximates an answer is speculation, really, unless you can find a quote from the film or one of its creators that says this applies to Cage as well.  Please read [answer] for more information on how to write a good answer.